# Sideshow Bob on Simpson's Tapped Out

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

On the Simpson's tapped out, what is the point of sideshow Bob showing up all the time? Is it just for money and experience finding him? Also, is there a specific condition that needs to be met to see him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He increases your Righteousness rating when you apprehend him. As far as I know this is the only way to do that, aside from cleaning up your friends' vandalism to your town, if you want to go into the "lol social gamez" side of things.

I'm pretty sure his appearances are just random to the tune of once every 1-2 weeks.

Comment: This past week, I actually saw him 1-2 times per day! Truly random I guess